# How to `complete` a partially filled in dataclass with optional attributes and pass type checks?

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing, python-dataclasses

## The problem

Suppose we have a Python dataclass `MyData` that is designed to store and perform operations with some data.
This dataclass consists of 3 elements, `a`, `b` and `c`:

- `a`  is mandatory and must be provided.
- `b` and `c` are optional, but at least one of them must be specified.
  If `b` is not given, we can compute it from `a` and `c` in `__post_init__`.
  Same goes for `c`. These computations are not cheap, and are defined in a function elsewhere in the code.

For us humans, if you provide `a` and at least one of `b` or `c`, we can assume that, after initialization, all attributes will be of type `float`, so we can pass instances of `MyData` around with that assumption in mind.
However, if you try doing that and run a static type checker like mypy, you will get errors -- because they still consider the case where they might be undefined.

**How does one implement this dataclass so type checkers like mypy will not complain?**

## My attempt

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import cast
from time import sleep

@dataclass
class MyData:
    a: float
    b: float | None = None
    c: float | None = None

    def __post_init__(self) -> None:
        self._complete_attributes()

    def _complete_attributes(self) -> None:
        """Checks for missing attributes and computes them if possible."""

        if self.b is None and self.c is None:
            # Both b and c are missing, oops!
            raise ValueError("Either b or c needs to be defined!")
        elif self.b is None:
            # b is missing but c is there
            # typing.cast does nothing in runtime but convinces mypy that c is not None
            # I don't like it being there but it suppresses a mypy error.
            # Is there a better way?
            self.c = cast(float, self.c)
            self.b = compute_b(self.a, self.c)
        elif self.c is None:
            # c is missing but b is there
            self.b = cast(float, self.b)
            self.c = compute_c(self.a, self.b)


def compute_b(a: float, c: float) -> float:
    sleep(10) # Simulate number-crunching
    return a + c

def compute_c(a: float, b: float) -> float:
    sleep(10) # Gotta think hard about this one
    return b - a
```

This appears to work without issues.
However, if you try to anything with `b` or `c`, such as:

```py
def do_stuff(data: MyData) -> float:
    return data.a * data.b
```

mypy will give an error:

```
error: Unsupported operand types for * ("float" and "None")  [operator]
note: Right operand is of type "Optional[float]"
```

**How do we get the desired behavior and keep static type checkers happy?**

Answer (score 0):

So, you can use a combination of `dataclasses.InitVar` (which indicates that the value is only used as an argument to `__init__`), and `field(init=False)` (to specify that a field should not produce a corresponding parameter for `__init__`), but this gets really messy:

```
import dataclasses

@dataclasses.dataclass
class MyData:
    a: float
    b: float = dataclasses.field(init=False)
    c: float = dataclasses.field(init=False)
    b_arg: dataclasses.InitVar[float | None] = None
    c_arg: dataclasses.InitVar[float | None] = None

    def __post_init__(self, b_arg, c_arg) -> None:
        self._complete_attributes(b_arg, c_arg)

    def _complete_attributes(self, b_arg, c_arg) -> None:
        """Checks for missing attributes and computes them if possible."""

        if b_arg is None and c_arg is None:
            # Both b and c are missing, oops!
            raise ValueError("Either b or c needs to be defined!")
        elif b_arg is None:
            # b is missing but c is there
            self.b = compute_b(self.a, c_arg)
            self.c = c_arg
        elif c_arg is None:
            # c is missing but b is there
            self.b = b_arg
            self.c = compute_c(self.a, b_arg)


def compute_b(a: float, c: float) -> float:
    return a + c

def compute_c(a: float, b: float) -> float:
    return b - a
```

Frankly, I would just abandon `dataclasses.dataclass` here, which is meant to make your code more *readable* and to avoid boilerplate, but the above is quite ugly and confusing. It would be much better to simply bite the bullet and write out the class definition without the code generator, IMO.

Comment: Also, not using dataclass would allow `overload` on `__init__` to make it explicit to the users that at least one of `{b, c}` must be provided. Dataclass will allow to remove only two-three lines of `__init__`, and this is a very tiny benefit given that other init logic is necessary anyway.